# Ecto: problems connecting to a remote postgres database

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm having problems getting my Phoenix app to connect to a remote database which has a password.

My `pg_hba.conf` file on posgres has this entry (for debugging);

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

With this setting in place, i can connect perfectly fine using `psql` but when i try to run migrations or do anything else with my phoenix app I get the following error.

```
** (Mix) The database for MyApp.Repo couldn't be created: FATAL (invalid_password): password authentication failed for user "postgres".
```

My config looks like this:

```
config :pancake, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: System.get_env("PG_USER"),
  password: System.get_env("PG_PASSWORD"),
  database: "myapp_prod",
  hostname: "postgres",
  pool_size: 10
```

I've tried changing the `pg_hba.conf` so that a password isn't required

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

With this change in place, i can connect no problem through my elxiier/phoenix app. Obviously this isn't a good solution long term. Does anyone have any idea why I can't provide a password?

Comment: What happens if you hard code the correct username and password in the config file? What arguments did you pass to `psql` that worked?

Comment: It turns out i didn't realize the the main config file was including another file `prod.secret.exs` which was overriding my db config.